# How do you update node menu links?

Tags: 8, nodes, navigation

I am creating Drupal 8 node using code and same time I am assigning a menu link as well its working fine. I am creating a menu using this code.

```
MenuLinkContent::create([
        'title' => $item['title'], // Menu title is your title of menu, in this case node title
        'link' => ['uri' => 'entity:node/' . $value->entity_id],
        'menu_name' => 'main',
        'expanded' => true,
        'parent' =>"menu_link_content:".$parent,
        'weight' => 0,
      ])->save();
```

Its working fine for me.
but I am not getting how to update these menus. Because its adding duplicate menu items when I am again creating node.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) You don't load the existing menu and check the existing links and update them? You just run create every time? You should implement some logic that loads the existing menu/items and resave them with new values I'd say.

Comment: I was trying to disable all links then update. but Unable to do this.